# drc_robot appears with no legs and no right hand.why?

Tags: gazebo-1.2

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

Whenever I insert drc_robot in gazebo( gazebo 1.2.6 and DRCsim 1.1 Ubuntu 12.04) using gui, I get this error message and the robot appears in the world with no right hand and no legs. What is going on here? Is that supposed to be like this?

```
   [ INFO] [1353527588.743735461]: Laser plugin missing <hokuyoMinIntensity>, defaults to 101
   [ INFO] [1353527588.743823824]: INFO: gazebo_ros_laser plugin should set minimum intensity to        101.000000 due to cutoff in hokuyo filters.
  [ERROR] [1353527588.745487217]: [registerPublisher] Failed to contact master at 
  [localhost:11311].  Retrying...
```

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/272/drc_robot-appears-with-no-legs-and-no-right-hand.why?/) by [Zara](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/32/zara/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 35 on 2012-11-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

please see [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/issue/17/added-robot-is-missing-parts)

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2012-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zara](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/32/zara/) on 2012-11-21**:
Thanks. I am not sure what WONTFIX flag means here for this issue.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2012-11-27**:
It means that sometime "soon" this issue will not matter as new files will be shared.